# Reading Azure Key Vault secret into ARM template via parameter file

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I've set up the problem in the these two files. The template is simply POSTing the parameter with a fake url to check the value.

read_secret_params.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "ftpPrivateKey": {
            "reference": {
                "keyVault": {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/dummyid/resourceGroups/dummyrg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/myvault"
                },
                "secretName": "mysecret"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

read_secret_template.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "ftpPrivateKey": {
            "type": "securestring"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2019-05-01",
            "name": "read-secret",
            "location": "East US",
            "properties": {
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "triggers": {
                        "Recurrence": {
                            "recurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Week",
                                "interval": 1
                            },
                            "type": "Recurrence"
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        "HTTP": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "body": "[parameters('ftpPrivateKey')]",
                                "method": "POST",
                                "uri": "https://dummysite.com"
                            },
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "Http"
                        }
                    },
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The first issue is, when I try to deploy via the portal, no value comes thru for the parameter so it can't create it due to the validation error **"Validation failed. Required information is missing or not valid."**. Is this because it's not able to read the secret, permissions thing? NOTE: the key vault is also created by myself so I am the owner.

[image]

I can get around the validation error and successfully deploy by adding a default value as follows:-

```
    "parameters": {
        "ftpPrivateKey": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "defaultValue": "privateKeyDefault"
        }
    },
```

But when I run the logic app, it's using the default value in the POST command so it seems like it's not pulling the secret out of the key vault.

[image]

So in summary I have 2 questions:-

1. Has this test proved that the logic app is not reading the secret OR might it have successfully read the secret but is for some reason displaying the default value in the POST command?
2. If it is not reading the secret, can anyone suggest a cause + fix?

Comment: Sorry but what’s the problem? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Well further down the chain, I'm trying to connect to an SFTP server using the private key which is stored as a secret in the Azure Key Vault. That's not working - I'm getting an "Invalid private key file". So my first stop is to determine if it's actually getting the private key from the vault or it's simply sending the default value.

Comment: This is a legitimate question, I’m not trying to be smart. Do you need to bake the private key into the core of the logic app design or could you refer to it at runtime?

Comment: No smartness taken. Appreciate the help! See what you mean-with this construct, the private key is baked in at deployment. As it happens, that's not really a problem in this case because they key is unlikely to change. Actually my first stab at this used AzureKeyVault->GetSecret() which worked well but then the result was produced in the Actions section and the rest of the SFTP credentials were set in the resources->properties->parameterValues section and didn't know how to bridge the two. Then I saw an example using the params file and thought, great.. nice n simple.But I'll take any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I deploy using the Azure CLI then it works i.e. gets the secret from Azure Key Vault. If deployed in the portal then it always uses the default value.